# SQL - how to use joins instead of EXISTS and NOT EXISTS in an Idempotent insert example

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I came across this github SQL code example for doing idempotent inserts. Works exactly how I want it. I don't want to use EXISTS though because I feel its a bit confusing. Can the same operation be coded with joins?

Below is same code I found at github: https://github.com/imtiazahmad007/SQL-Tips-Techniques/blob/master/Idempotent_Postgres_Inserts.sql

```
INSERT INTO users_articles (date, user_id, hit_count)
SELECT a.date, a.user_id, sum(a.article_id as hits)  
from (
select t.* from users_article_details AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM do_not_email_users_tbl
    WHERE email = t.email
    LIMIT 1
)) a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 from users_articles b
WHERE b.date = a.date)
GROUP BY date, user_id
```

Comment: It's not well written anyway. Too much nesting of queries, inconsistent use of table aliases, no idea why "as hits" is in there. NOT EXISTS is the very least of the problems. Personally I disagree with the premise of the question -- NOT EXISTS is standard and widely encountered SQL, it's a very efficient way of achieving the result (particularly if the subquery can return multiple rows for the values passed in from the main query), and the query is likely to be transformed by the optimizer to an efficient anti-join anyway.

Comment: You should profile the answers from prothid and Bob Jarvis. Different RDBMS will have different performance characteristics, and one may be _much_ slower than the other.

Comment: Is this for Oracle or Postgres? Your tags are confusing.

Comment: I question the use of `SUM(a.ARTICLE_ID)` in this SQL.  The article ID's are being summed up to get...what?  The column name indicates it's the number of hits or views, but this doesn't make sense to me as the only way it could work AFAICT is if ARTICLE_ID was always 1.  Perhaps what was intended was `COUNT(DISTINCT a.ARTICLE_ID)`?  ???

Comment: ... and the LIMIT 1 is redundant.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - kind of makes me wonder why the question is tagged for `oracle` since the LIMIT clause isn't valid for Oracle - and the github tree indicates it's for PostgreSQL.  ???

Answer (score 3):

I favor using outer joins for this kind of thing.  Try:

```
INSERT INTO USERS_ARTICLES (DATE, USER_ID, HIT_COUNT)
  SELECT a.DATE,
         a.USER_ID,
         SUM(a.ARTICLE_ID) AS HITS
    FROM USERS_ARTICLE_DETAILS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DO_NOT_EMAIL_USERS_TBL n
      ON (n.EMAIL = a.EMAIL)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS_ARTICLES b
      ON (b.DATE = a.DATE)
    WHERE n.EMAIL IS NULL AND
          b.DATE IS NULL
    GROUP BY DATE, USER_ID
```

Using the reserved word DATE for a column name might potentially cause issues - if so, surround DATE in double-quotes (e.g. "DATE").

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You're doing `users_articles_details a LEFT OUTER JOIN do_not_email_users_tbl n on (n.email = a.email)`. Won't this only filter users that have email addresses matching the ones in do_not_email_users_tbl? I want only those users that I am allowed to send emails to and filter out the rest. Could you explain your left outer joins?

Comment: @user2081579 - The left outer join says "include all rows in the left table (USERS_ARTICLE_DETAILS) and add data for rows in the right table (DO_NOT_EMAIL_USERS_TBL and USERS_ARTICLES, in separate joins) which match on the specified criteria".  In the WHERE clause we then accept only those joined rows which did not find a match in the right tables by looking for NULLs in fields which must be non-NULL if a right-side row was found.  So, if there's no data from DO_NOT_EMAIL_USERS_TBL (we know this because n.EMAIL is NULL) it's OK to send them an email. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @user2081579 - further info - IMO the advantage of using joins rather than EXISTS/NOT EXISTS is portability of performance.  Some databases, such as Oracle, are pretty good about transforming EXISTS/NOT EXISTS into an equivalent OUTER JOIN - but others don't do so well at this and may try performing the EXISTS sub-select for each individual row in the main table.  This can be a performance black hole.  But with appropriate indexes in place most relational databases can handle joins reasonably well as joins are fundamental to relational databases.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO
  users_articles
  (date, user_id, hit_count)
SELECT
  uad.date,
  uad.user_id,
  SUM(uad.article_id) AS hits
FROM
  users_article_details uad
WHERE
  uad.email NOT IN (select email from do_not_email_user_table where email=uad.email) AND
  uad.date NOT IN (select `date` from users_articles where `date`=uad.date and user_id=uad.user_id)
GROUP BY
  uad.date,
  uad.user_id;
```

Comment: You could leave the predicates out of the subqueries -- using NOT IN on a correlated subquery looks a bit strange. Maybe you included it in case any of the subqueries return a null value, which is the drawback of NOT IN.

Comment: It's just more readable IMO. Sometimes you'll get some improved performance from the query planner by dropping some hints, too.  I also fixed an error in my query where the submitter forgot to cross-reference user id in the users_articles table when checking for duplicate dates.